# Search column of one sheet and return multiple matches from a separate sheet in CSV

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am trying to search Data!A2:A for multiple matches to Search!A2:A.  When a match is found, get the value(s) from Data!B2:B and place them in CSV format in Search!B2:B.

This `QUERY` works, but I would like to somehow only enter it one time at the top of the column rather than fill it down manually.  When I attempted to wrap it in `ARRAYFORMULA`, I simply replicated the first result down the column.

```excel
=JOIN(", ",QUERY(Data!$A$2:$B,"SELECT B WHERE A = '"&A2&"'",0))
```

Here is my [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12cOm-PGSKmPpH0stDMkCUWgQbXV1oF3JREM6FOSUQfM/edit#gid=0&range=B2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {QUERY(QUERY(Data!A2:B, 
 "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0), "select Col1 offset 1", 0),
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(QUERY(Data!A2:B, 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0), "offset 1", 0)), 
 QUERY(QUERY(Data!A2:B, 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0), "limit 0", -1)&",", ))
 ,,999^99))}, 2, 0))), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]